# Open Safari from iPhone's WIFI login page

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari

I'am developing a WIFI subscription login page (example : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3867)

iPhone doesn't open these login pages in Safari but instead in a special frame (a UIWebView i think)

From this page i want to add a button that redirects to our website but opens in Safari and not in the same frame.

Is that possible in HTML or javascript?